# How can I use the Container's ENV on DATABASE_URL Symfony

Tags: symfony, docker

I have the following environment on my php container like so:

```
DATABASE_URL:mysql://root:${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}@db:3306/${MYSQL_DATABASE}
```

I tried to echo it inside my container, and do a db migration. All is good. Now I used it on my .env file on symfony like so:

```
DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
```

When i tried to login, the app says:

> Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

When i try to manually put everything on .env DATABASE_URL all is good.

I suspect that when I tried to use the container's ENV it doesn't get it right.

My question is how can I use the actual Containers' environment variable?

Thanks!

Note:

I on dev environment.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite familiar with symfony, but it seems like symfony never overwrites existing environment variables. (Ref: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html)

What if you remove that line in your `.env` file? Since `DATABASE_URL` is already an environment variable, calling `getenv('DATABASE_URL')` in symfony should return you the correct value even if you did not define it in `.env`. All `dotenv` does it to write those key value pairs as environment variables in your system. You don't need to define it again if it is already present.

Comment: Can you try printing the value from `getenv('DATABASE_URL')` somewhere in your application and see what it shows? Also, when you said you tried echo-ing, I suppose you did `echo $DATABASE_URL`?

Answer (score 2):

note that there is separate environments when you run php from cli and when it gets run by webserver (when you access it from your browser).

For example, in case of nginx-fpm, the variables that you see in your cli by running `printenv` are not avaiable in php script run by nginx when you call `getenv()`. In order to set environment variable for php fpm you can edit `php-fpm.conf`:

```
....
[www]
env[DATABASE_URL] = 'mysql://...'
....
```

If you use another webserver than you should find out how to make env vars available in php script.

Your `DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}` in `.env` file didn't work bacause `DATABASE_URL` was not set for php fpm.

Hope this helps.

P.S. Note, that this construction `VAR=${VAR}` makes nothing because DotEnv will not override `VAR` as it is already defined.

P.P.S. It is advised that you use `.env` file for your dev server and "real" env variables in staging/production.